# Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design updates itself when i try to scaffold new identity

Tags: .net, nuget, asp.net-identity, code-generation, scaffolding

I am using .net 8 prev version and downgraded my projects' packages to 4.23 from 5.23 because 5.23 was giving an error. all my packages are in sync with 4.23 and no problem building it. When i try to add a new scaffold identity item to my web project it automatically updates my CodeGeneration package to 5.23 which result in an error due to packages are incompatible